# Can not get Value from a Web Service

Tags: go, postman

I am starting to learn Go and I am facing error. I tried to run in Postman but I cannot get the value. I expect to get the first value from data.

Below is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

type student struct {
    ID    string
    Name  string
    Grade int
}

var data = []student{
    {"E001", "ethan", 21},
    {"W001", "wick", 22},
    {"B001", "bourne", 23},
    {"B002", "bond", 23},
}

func users(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    if r.Method == "POST" {
        var result, err = json.Marshal(data)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }
        w.Write(result)
        return
    }
    http.Error(w, "", http.StatusBadRequest)
}

func user(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    if r.Method == "POST" {
        var id = r.FormValue("id")
        var result []byte
        var err error
        for _, each := range data {
            if each.ID == id {
                result, err = json.Marshal(each)
                if err != nil {
                    http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
                    return
                }
                w.Write(result)
                return
            }
        }
        http.Error(w, "User not found", http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }
    http.Error(w, "", http.StatusBadRequest)
}
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/users", users)
    http.HandleFunc("/user", user)
    fmt.Println("starting web server at http://localhost:8080/")
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

[When I run in Postman, I cannot get the value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wju5q.png)

Can anyone please give me advise on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Is there a code responsible for `id` form value setting?

Comment: In postman, specify an `id` query parameter with the valid ID of a student.

Comment: So may i know how do i fix the code ?

Comment: The code in the question works as is.  The problem is that the you are not specifying the `id` query parameter in the client.  Here's the code working in the playground https://play.golang.org/p/gOJ5Sniq-dc.   A GET request is more conventional than a POST request for this scenario.

Comment: Hi All, now i understand why it was raise an error.  I have to give value  id in postman and it give me the expected value. Thanks for your help.